Binary classification in pytorch
I want to make a binary classification. The classes in the original data set are unbalanced, 90% and 10%. When using CrossEntropyLoss() at the exit of my function, I get that all objects belong to the null class
At the same time, I tried to iterate over the hyperparameters of the model, but it did not help
I have great doubts that I am using the CrossEntropyLoss loss function correctly, but searching the Internet did not help me find the answer to this question
import torch
from torch import nn , optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

x = df_train.drop(['Response'], axis =1) #Response - Target
y = df_train['Response']
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, stratify=y)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = x_train.to_numpy(), x_test.to_numpy(), y_train.to_numpy(), y_test.to_numpy()

class model_nn(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self,input_size,output_size):
        super(model_nn,self).__init__()
        
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.output_size= output_size
        
        self.linear_1 = nn.Linear(self.input_size, 10)
        self.act_1    = nn.Tanh()
        self.linear_2 = nn.Linear(10, self.output_size)
        self.softmax =  nn.Softmax()
        self.act_2 = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.double() 
        
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.act_1(self.linear_1(x))
        x = self.act_2(self.linear_2(x))
        return x
    
model =  model_nn(10,2).to(device)


class Dataset(Dataset):
    
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        
        self.x = torch.from_numpy(x)
        self.y = torch.from_numpy(y)
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        
        return self.x[index], self.y[index]
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.x)
    
train_dataset = Dataset(x_train, y_train)
test_dataset  = Dataset(x_test, y_test)
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset = train_dataset, batch_size=256, shuffle=True)
test_loader  = DataLoader(dataset = test_dataset,  batch_size=256, shuffle=True)
optimazer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr = 0.01)
loss_fm   = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()


def train(model,train_loader,test_loader):
    
    
    for epoch in range(40):
        run_loss_train = 0
        run_loss_valid = 0
        for num_batch, (inputs , outputs) in enumerate(train_loader):
            model.train()
            inputs = inputs.to(device)
            outputs = outputs.to(device)
            optimazer.zero_grad()
            predict_outputs = model(inputs)
            loss = loss_fm(predict_outputs, outputs.long() )
    
            loss.backward()
            optimazer.step()
            run_loss_train += loss.item()
        run_loss_train = run_loss_train/num_batch
            
        with torch.no_grad():
            model.eval()
            for num_batch_val, (inpiut , output) in enumerate(test_loader):
                
                predict_out = model(inpiut)
                loss = loss_fm(predict_out,output.long())
                run_loss_valid += loss.item()
        run_loss_valid = run_loss_valid/num_batch_val
        if epoch%10 == 0:
            print(epoch,'run_loss_train',np.round(run_loss_train,3), 'run_loss_valid',np.round(run_loss_valid,3))
train(model,train_loader,test_loader)

please tell me, what am I doing wrong?

can you elaborate further on the problem you have received? To obtain the class, you need to apply torch.argmax. The outputs are probabilities.
For binary classification, should be using nn.BCELoss.
import torch
from torch import nn , optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

x = df_train.drop(['Response'], axis =1) #Response - Target
y = df_train['Response']
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, stratify=y)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = x_train.to_numpy(), x_test.to_numpy(), y_train.to_numpy(), y_test.to_numpy()

class model_nn(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self,input_size,output_size):
        super(model_nn,self).__init__()
        
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.output_size= output_size
        
        self.linear_1 = nn.Linear(self.input_size, 10)
        self.act_1    = nn.Tanh()
        self.linear_2 = nn.Linear(10, self.output_size)
        self.softmax =  nn.Softmax()
        self.act_2 = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.double() 
        
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.act_1(self.linear_1(x))
        x = self.act_2(self.linear_2(x))
        return x
    
model =  model_nn(10,2).to(device)


class Dataset(Dataset):
    
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        
        self.x = torch.from_numpy(x)
        self.y = torch.from_numpy(y)
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        
        return self.x[index], self.y[index]
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.x)
    
train_dataset = Dataset(x_train, y_train)
test_dataset  = Dataset(x_test, y_test)
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset = train_dataset, batch_size=256, shuffle=True)
test_loader  = DataLoader(dataset = test_dataset,  batch_size=256, shuffle=True)
optimazer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr = 0.01)
loss_fm   = nn.BCELoss()


def train(model,train_loader,test_loader):
    
    
    for epoch in range(40):
        run_loss_train = 0
        run_loss_valid = 0
        for num_batch, (inputs , outputs) in enumerate(train_loader):
            model.train()
            inputs = inputs.to(device)
            outputs = outputs.to(device)
            optimazer.zero_grad()
            predict_outputs = model(inputs)
            loss = loss_fm(predict_outputs, outputs.long() )
    
            loss.backward()
            optimazer.step()
            run_loss_train += loss.item()
        run_loss_train = run_loss_train/num_batch
            
        with torch.no_grad():
            model.eval()
            for num_batch_val, (inpiut , output) in enumerate(test_loader):
                
                predict_out = model(inpiut)
                loss = loss_fm(predict_out,output.long())
                run_loss_valid += loss.item()
        run_loss_valid = run_loss_valid/num_batch_val
        if epoch%10 == 0:
            print(epoch,'run_loss_train',np.round(run_loss_train,3), 'run_loss_valid',np.round(run_loss_valid,3))
train(model,train_loader,test_loader)


